# twilio auto-call in API with python

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I'm running a web server in Python with twilio credentials.

When my user presses a button, I want to be able to do all the connecting of the conference call so they don't have to.

Phone numbers involved: `conference_line`, `my_twilio_number`, `user_number`

1. web server makes twilio outgoing-api call -> `my_twilio_number`
2. `my_twilio_number` responds with TwiML that Dials `conference_line`
3. once connected to `conference_line`, status_callback sent back to my API server
4. this endpoint responds with a TwiML that calls to=`user_number` using callerId for from=`my_twilio_number`

I have the first three steps working perfectly. However on the last step, I return the TwiML and then ... nothing. Not sure how to debug this since Twilio isn't throwing any errors.

For reference, the TwiML on step 3 is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+{my_twilio_number}">
        <Number>{user_number}</Number>      
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

How should I debug this? What is likely going wrong?

Or do asynchronous status_callback HTTP requests not act on TwiML responses?

Comment: Maybe we can see your python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The status callback webhooks don't expect TwiML in a response and won't take any action.

If you want to make the call once the person is connected using the callback, then I suggest you use the [REST API to make the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) to your user number.